# Dense subset in $R$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

It is known that the set $\{(\cos m\theta,\sin m\theta)\}_{m=0}^\infty$ is dense in the unit circle.
Can we show that the set $D=\{\frac{1}{A\sin m\theta+B\cos m\theta}\}_{m=0}^\infty$ is dense in $R-(-\inf D,\inf D)$?
where $A\sin m\theta+B\cos m\theta\neq0$ for all $m\in N$ and $\theta$ is an irrational multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: No: $|A\sin m\theta+B\cos m\theta|\le|A|+|B|$, so $1/(|A|+|B|)$ is a lower bound for your expression in absolute value, and no point in $(-1/(|A|+|B|),1/(|A|+|B|))$ is of the required form. Perhaps the question should be if the set is dense outside of the interval $(-inf,inf)$, where $inf$ is the infimum of the absolute values of the members of your set.

Comment: OK! You are right! set  the set   $$D=\{\frac{1}{A \sin m\theta+B\cos m\theta\}_{m=0}^\infty$$ is dense in $R-(-\inf D,\inf D)$. Please supply me with a sketch for the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$
f(x,y)= \frac{1}{Bx+Ay}
$$
for $\ (x,y)\ $ on the unit circle $\ S_1\ $.  Then $\ f\ $ is a continuous function from $\ S_1\ $ onto $\ X=\left(-\infty,-\sqrt{A^2+B^2} \right]\cup\left[\sqrt{A^2+B^2}, \infty\right)\ $, with $\ f(\cos m\theta, \sin m\theta)=\frac{1}{B\cos m\theta+A\sin m\theta}\ $, so the density of $\ D\ $ in $\ X\ $ then follows from that of $\ \left\{(\cos m\theta, \sin m\theta)\right\}_{m=0}^\infty\ $ in $\ S_1\ $.

Comment: Thank you @Lonzaleggiera